# Query Help Get Exact Date Time Difference

Tags: mysql

I have a query that gets the difference in time and date from the time the record was inserted vs the current date.

Here is the Example.

```
select
datediff(date(now()),'2012-04-15 16:14:59') as DateDifference,
timediff(now(), '2012-04-15 16:14:59') as TimeDifference
```

But this one give me the following result:

> Date Difference Time Difference
>   5               112:26:22

I really want to get the exact difference between the two.

Example:

> 5 8:24:22

where 5 is the day and 8:24:22 is the time.

Comment: What do you want exactly? 112:26:22 is not 5 days, 8 hours, 24 minutes and 22 seconds, but merely 4 days, 16 hours, 24 minutes and 22 seconds. Which of the two do you want to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT floor((date1-date2)*24) || ' HOURS ' ||
mod(floor((date1-date2)*24*60),60) || ' MINUTES ' ||
mod(floor((date1-date2)*24*60*60),60) || ' SECS ' as time_difference
FROM dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 75 );
TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```

And the output would be :

```
Time Difference (seconds): 15
Time Difference (minutes): 1
Time Difference (hours): 0
Time Difference (days): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select 
date(now()) date1, 
date('2012-04-15 16:14:59') date2,
datediff(date(now()),'2012-04-15 16:14:59') as DateDifference,
TIME(now()) time1, 
TIME('2012-04-15 16:14:59') time2, 
timediff(TIME(now()), TIME('2012-04-15 16:14:59')) as TimeDifference
```

This will give you exact differences and comparison.

Hope this helps.